# Stability of SQLCipher Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqlcipher

General question about the stability of SQLCipher in Android, and whether the github [readme](https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher) may just need an update.  The latest full description of the libraries is very old (May 11) and reads:

> the Android support libraries in this release are still very much alpha quality, hence the Developer Preview label.

On the other hand, Zetetic [offers a commercial binary](http://sqlcipher.net/downloads/), Mark Murphy has [a project which uses it](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Database/ConstantsSecure), and he also endorsed using the library in [June](http://community.developer.motorola.com/t5/MOTODEV-Blog/SQLCipher-for-Android-and-You/ba-p/27070) with no mention of instability.   So, can I safely assume that comment no longer applies and SQLCipher is actually ready for production use (if I am only targeting 2.3 and up)?

Comment: That's probably a better question to ask on http://groups.google.com/group/sqlcipher

Comment: thank you. i did not see much written on github but did somehow miss that group. i have relocated this post there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting on behalf of Nick, the response from the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/group/sqlcipher/browse_frm/thread/c161f0cd76f11c60)

> Yes, we do need to update the README to reflect a more accurate description of the state of SQLCipher for Android.  It is stable, and there are several applications using it in production available on the Google Play store.  We have verified it's test suite on Android versions 2.1 through 4.0.3.  We have been running it successfully on 4.1 as well.  I will get a more accurate README file available soon.  Let us know if you have any questions.  Thanks!

Comment: yes, thanks for cross-posting this back here for others coming across this thread.